# Sublime: Keep getting an EOF Error in python shell

Tags: python, sublimetext2, user-input, eof

```
number = input("Enter a non-negative integer: ")
```

Whenever I try to run this, I get en EOF error. I'm using Sublime Text 2 and Python 2.6.1.
The funny thing is that when I ran this in my terminal, it worked fine.

Comment: Can you post the full error?

Comment: If its looking for the EOF character to end you string instead of new line, you can pass that by using CTRL+D.

Comment: Is it not better to use ``number = int(raw_input("Enter.."))`` as ``input`` == ``eval(raw_input(prompt))`` - it's something that's always confused me as to why people use ``input``.